# How to make sure that click functions are only performed once

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks on either `.class` or `#id`, some changes are made to the css of both divs and the value of `#id` increases by 1. However, when the user clicks on either one of the divs, the changes should only be made once - if the user clicks again, nothing will happen unless the page is refreshed.

```
$('.class, #id').one('click', function(e) {
   $('.class, #id').css({
   'background-color' : 'rgb(232,69,73)',
   'color' : '#fff',
   });
 $("#id").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
 });
```

Above shows the code that I am using. As you can see, I have used `.one` to make sure that the code is only performed **once**. This works, but the problem is that the user can click on `.class` and then click on `#div` which means that the code can be performed **twice**.

How would I edit this so that the code can only be performed once - clicking on one div means the other div can not be clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **set a data attribute on both objects** and only increment the counter if that is not set:

```
$('.class, #id').one('click', function(e) {
   if (!$(this).data("valueSet")) {
       $('.class, #id').css({
           'background-color' : 'rgb(232,69,73)',
           'color' : '#fff'
       }).data("valueSet", true);
       $("#id").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    }
 });
```

Or, if you know there are no other jQuery click handlers that you want to retain, **you can unbind all jQuery click handlers from both objects**:

```
$('.class, #id').one('click', function(e) {
    $('.class, #id').off("click").css({
        'background-color' : 'rgb(232,69,73)',
        'color' : '#fff'
    })
    $("#id").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
 });
```

Or, you can **unbind just this specific event handler** by putting the event handler in a named function:

```
function oneClick(e) {
    $('.class, #id').off("click", oneClick).css({
        'background-color' : 'rgb(232,69,73)',
        'color' : '#fff'
    })
    $("#id").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
}

$('.class, #id').one('click', oneClick);
```

---

A **little more generic scheme** would create a custom function that will only ever perform its action once:

```
function oneAction(fn) {
     var calledYet = false;
     return function() {
          if (!calledYet) {
              calledYet = true;
              return fn.apply(this, arguments);
          }
     }
 }
```

Then, you can use this:

```
$('.class, #id').one('click', oneAction(function(e) {
    // this will only ever be executed once
    $('.class, #id').css({
        'background-color' : 'rgb(232,69,73)',
        'color' : '#fff'
    })
    $("#id").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
}));
```

Comment: I think I would opt for using `one` with event delegation since it won't keep the handler around. Not only that, but some of the proposed solutions wouldn't play nice with other handlers. If you want to manually call `off`, I would opt for a named function expression which can be referenced in `off`.

Comment: @plalx - I offered three different choices that play just fine with other click handlers and documented the one that doesn't.  Your delegated option is creative.

Comment: True, I guess I just focused on one part of your answer; my bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use one with event delegation instead. That way you have a single handler for all targets and jQuery will automatically remove it once invoked.

```js
$(document).one('click', '#first,#second', alert.bind(null, 'clicked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first">first</button>
<button id="second">second</button>
```

With your code it would be:

```
$(document).one('click', '.class, #id', function(e) {
    //handle click
});
```

Here's another example showing how you could manually remove the handler after invocation in a safe way (without affecting other handlers) using a named function expression:

```js
$('#first, #second').click(function someClickHandler(e) {
  alert('clicked!');
  
  $('#first, #second').off('click', someClickHandler);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting two listeners, in fact. One on the `.class` and another on the `#id`.

This means you'll need to store a state variable and check it before performing any action.

```
var isClickable = true;
$('.class, #id').one('click', function(e) {
   if(isClickable){
     isClickable = false;
     $('.class, #id').css({
     'background-color' : 'rgb(232,69,73)',
     'color' : '#fff',
     });
   $("#id").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
  }
 });
```

This is a better option than adding a state attribute to the actual DOM element.

Comment: Why is creating a **global variable** better than adding a state attribute to each DOM element?

Comment: Updating the DOM is more expensive than storing a variable in memory.